# what on earth the unicode number is?

Tags: python, r, unicode

in python:

```
>>> "\xc4\xe3".decode("gbk").encode("utf-8")
'\xe4\xbd\xa0'
>>> "\xc4\xe3".decode("gbk")
u'\u4f60'
```

we can get two conclusions:

1.\xc4\xe3 in gbk encode = \xe4\xbd\xa0  in utf-8
2.\xc4\xe3 in gbk encode = \x4f\x60  in unicode(or say in ucs-2)

in R:

```
> iconv("\xc4\xe3",from="gbk",to="utf-8",toRaw=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] e4 bd a0
> iconv("\xc4\xe3",from="gbk",to="unicode",toRaw=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] ff fe 60 4f
```

now ,the conclusion1 is correct ,it is as same  in python as in R
conclusion2 is a puzzle,
what on earth is the  \xc4\xe3 in gbk encode = ??  in unicode.
in python it is u'\u4f60',in R it is ff fe 60 4f
are the equal? which one is correct?are they all correct?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: [Unicode in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode): *"Unicode can be implemented by different character encodings. The most commonly used encodings are UTF-8, UTF-16 and the now-obsolete UCS-2...."*

Comment: This wikipedia article discusses GBK encoding.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK  This article describes Unicode in python http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Please, read the article under @delnan's comment - really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python, the `\uxxxx` notation refers to Unicode codepoints, not to any *encoding* of those codepoints.

UCS-2, UTF-16, UTF-8 are all encodings capable of capturing those codepoints in bytes suitable for storage in files, for transferring across a network, etc.

The R representation of the `\u4f60` codepoint includes the UTF-16 [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), or BOM. It indicates what byte order is chosen, where 0xFFFE means little endian. Python includes it too, when you encode to UTF-16:

```
>>> u'\uf460'.encode('utf16')
'\xff\xfe`\xf4'
```

The big-endian equivalent is 0xFEFF. You can explicitly encode to `utf-16be` or `utf-16le` in python to avoid the BOM being included, because you've made an explicit choice:

```
>>> u'\uf460'.encode('utf-16be')
'\xf4`'
>>> u'\uf460'.encode('utf-16le')
'`\xf4'
```

You really should read the Joel Spolsky [Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) article, as well as the Python [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) to more fully appreciate the difference between Unicode and encodings.