# how to get the unicode format of "你"?

Tags: python

I knew that  the unicode of  `你`  (meaning `you`) is  \x4F\x60.
How can i get it from my python command console?

```
>>> print("你")
你
>>> print(("你").encode("gbk"))
b'\xc4\xe3'
>>> print(("你").encode("utf-8"))
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0
```

I am in python3.3  .

Comment: That character *in some encoding* may be \x4F\x60, but there is no such thing as "the unicode of" a character.

Comment: `\x4F\x60` is a string-representation of the unicode point by escaping the points with hexadecimal, usually done to avoid problems with the source code file being saved in an encoding that doesn't support all the unicode code points. However, the term "unicode of" is misleading. The unicode code point X has a hexadecimal string representation Y is much better.

Comment: "The unicode of" **is** well defined (each character in unicode has a unique number associated with it, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). The encoding of the unicode is a different story.

Comment: @freakish No, there is no such thing. There are **code points**, which are encoding-agnostic and commonly referred to as characters (though this is not the best definition of character IMHO), but that's not called "the unicode of" the character.

Comment: @freakish: the Unicode code point may be well defined, I don't think you can call that "the unicode of" a character.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich What else could "the unicode of" mean?

Comment: It means nothing, it is not a correct term for anything. You have unicode code points, they have an ordinal value, they can also be represented in strings (usually) through hexadecimal escape values (of those ordinal values). But X is not "the unicode of" Y, because "the unicode of" is not a term for anything. You can invent a meaning though. Also note that the escape syntax is language dependent and is not something defined by the unicode standard. The unicode code points, however, are.

Comment: Well in my view it is meaningless.

Comment: @freakish It could mean the person doesn't know enough about Unicode to even distinguish code points and the numerous other things Unicode defines (various encodings, grapheme clusters, etc.). It's not a common term anywhere, and although the three of us seem to interpret it the same way, there is no use in inventing new terms.

Comment: @freakish: If we're into sloppy terminology, then "the unicode of" might mean for example the UTF-8 representation of that code point.

Comment: @TadeuszA.Kadłubowski No, that is a "code unit". The correct term for the ordinal values are "code point". You have characters, such as "A", code point, such as 65 (or U+0041), and code units (which depend on the encoding). All of these things are well defined in the Unicode specification, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) for details for instance.

Comment: What he's asking for is either the code point or the code unit, but seeing as the values given as examples are 8-bit, it is most likely a code unit in an encoding, or he has simply tried to represent one unicode character as a byte-array (which would give him two bytes in the array).

Comment: @TadeuszA.Kadłubowski Yeah, it's like saying "cow can mean horse". I know that most people tend to think that unicode and utf-8 it's just different words for the same thing, but it's not. Perhaps OP does want utf-8 representation. But the fact is that he asked about *unicode*, not *utf-8*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
>>> print(("你").encode("unicode-escape"))
b"\\u4f60"
```

Which shows that 你 is \u4F60. I don't know a specific encoding that turns that into the two bytes 4F and 60.

(I only tested this on 2.7.3, assuming that "unicode-escape" also exists in Python 3)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the actual unicode *codepoint* of any given character in Python 3, you can simply use `ord` to get the raw number

```
>>> ord('你')
20320
```

However, you really should search around and you might find answers in other SO articles like

- [what on earth the unicode number is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330198/what-on-earth-the-unicode-number-is?rq=1)

Also read up on what [Unicode actually is](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), which was also linked there.

Comment: +1 for linking to Joel Spolsky's The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)